# Calculating values of derived attributes in SQL

Tags: sql, xampp

I have a restaurant database with two tables. One of the tables is `'item'` with the following attributes :

```
ItemID, ItemName, Price and Cuisine.
```

I have another table `'bill'` which has the following attributes:

```
OrderID, Item1_ID, Item2_ID, Item3_ID, Quantity_1, Quantity_2, Quantity_3, Total.
```

The 2nd, 3rd and 4th attributes of bill specify 3 items with different ItemID and the 5th, 6th and 7th attributes specify their respective quantities. I want to calculate the price of each item by multiplying with their respective quantities with their Price(taken from the 'item' table) and then add their individual prices and save the result in total.

1.I'm able to generate the three individual prices but since they're derived attributes, I cannot save them and hence update the 'Total' attribute of 'bill'. How do I do this? This is the code I'm using to generate the three individual prices :

```
SELECT A.Total_1, B.Total_2, C.Total_3
FROM
(SELECT bill.orderid, bill.quantity_1 * item.Price AS 'Total_1'
FROM bill, item 
WHERE item.itemid = bill.item_1
)A,

(SELECT bill.orderid, bill.quantity_2 * item.Price AS 'Total_2'
FROM bill, item 
WHERE item.itemid = bill.item_2
)B,

(SELECT bill.orderid, bill.quantity_3 * item.Price AS 'Total_3'
FROM bill, item 
WHERE item.itemid = bill.item_3
)C

WHERE A.orderid = B.orderid AND A.orderid = C.orderid;
```

2. Should I remove the attribute 'Total' since it's derived? I do wish to use its value in another table so is their any other way I can approach this?

Comment: You want do instant calculate total amount after insert your itemes and quantity in your database ?

Comment: No. I've already inserted the items and quantity. I want to run query to calculate the total as and when required.

Comment: You seams no to have a problem, your item cand be in either position in bill table ? I mean you can have THIS EXAMPLE: bill1 item_1 = idItem1 .., bill2 item_1 = idItem3 item_2 =idItem1 ... bill3 item_1 = idItem3 item_2 = idItem_2 item_3 = idItem3 ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use somting like this:

```
select 
    item_1 * price_1 + item_2 * price_2 + item_3 * price_3 as total
    item_1 * price_1 as total_1
    item_2 * price_2 as total_2
    item_3 * price_3 as total_3
where orderId = yourOrderId
```

if you do logical operation in your select (+,*,/,-) is same fast like your take separat your item and do your operation in your favorite language.

Comment: It won't work because I need to use separate itemID for each item. And I'd have to specify that in the 'Where' statement.

Comment: ok you can have combination? I mean if have 1 item with id =1, in billing can have this combination with your items id : (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1) where every position idicate your item_pozition and where is 1 this mean you have 3 billing with different order of your items.

Comment: So that way I'd have to make 3 entries for each orderID, right? And then calculate row by row and update the total? I'll try that.

Comment: Yes, this is more easy and optimized, if you want have a raport for every item you can do only a simple join to see total for every item solded.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution would be to use your existing query as a derived table and select from it:

```
SELECT Total_1, Total_2, Total_3, 
 Total_1 + Total_2 + Total_3 AS GrandTotal
FROM (
SELECT A.Total_1, B.Total_2, C.Total_3
FROM
(SELECT bill.orderid, bill.quantity_1 * item.Price AS 'Total_1'
FROM bill, item 
WHERE item.itemid = bill.item_1
)A,

(SELECT bill.orderid, bill.quantity_2 * item.Price AS 'Total_2'
FROM bill, item 
WHERE item.itemid = bill.item_2
)B,

(SELECT bill.orderid, bill.quantity_3 * item.Price AS 'Total_3'
FROM bill, item 
WHERE item.itemid = bill.item_3
)C

WHERE A.orderid = B.orderid AND A.orderid = C.orderid
) T;
```

EDIT:

To store `GrandTotal` in the `Total` column in table `Bill` you could do this:

```
UPDATE b2
SET Total = (
 SELECT A.Total_1 + B.Total_2 + C.Total_3
    FROM
    (SELECT bill.quantity_1 * item.Price AS 'Total_1'
    FROM bill, item 
    WHERE item.itemid = bill.item_1
    AND bill.Orderid=b2.Orderid
    )A,

    (SELECT bill.quantity_2 * item.Price AS 'Total_2'
    FROM bill, item 
    WHERE item.itemid = bill.item_2
    AND bill.Orderid=b2.Orderid
    )B,

    (SELECT bill.quantity_3 * item.Price AS 'Total_3'
    FROM bill, item 
    WHERE item.itemid = bill.item_3
    AND bill.Orderid=b2.Orderid
    )C
)
FROM Bill b2
```

Comment: I wish to store the variable you've defined as 'GrandTotal' because I want to use it for further queries. If I select it using AS, I won't be able to do that, right?

Comment: Sure you will.   What makes you think that you won't?

Comment: Will the result get saved? I mean every time I execute this query, I'll be able to see the total but what if I want to execute another query after this where I want to use the total value to update information in another table?

Comment: Well you have to code it to save the result, and how you do that depends on how you want it saved, but it's certainly possible to do it a number of different ways.

Comment: Could you explain how do I save this? I just want to save the GrandTotal.

Comment: Depends.    Save it where?   For how long?

Comment: Just add the value of GrandTotal in another attribute which already exists in the table 'bill'.

Comment: Then you would do an UPDATE of table bill and use the query in the answer above (or one like it) to set the value of the attribute you want to store GrandTotal in.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for this. 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Bill b2' at line 23